# Proposal: remove [filtering] tag, replace with [quality-control] when appropriate

Tags: discussion

As of 2019-01-28, there are 16 posts tagged with `[filtering]`. This is an ambiguous and, at least in some cases, unhelpful term. Some of these posts are about quality control, some are about ranking, some are about data sampling, and some are about eliminating redundancy.

I propose we eliminate the `[filtering]` tag. The `[quality-control]` tag can replace it as appropriate, while in many other cases it can probably just be removed.

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest the following changes

- Replace `[filtering]` with `[quality-control]`:

  - [Output from vcftools missingness](https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/q/6890/96)
  - [Delete all 4 lines of a fastq read from a fastq file using read ID](https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/q/5327/96)
  - [Error filtering SNPs with Plink](https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/q/4235/96)
  - [Single-cell RNA sequencing (scRNA-seq): filtering cells by transcript counts, how to choose cutoffs?](https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/q/3140/96)
  - [Filter out outliers of the scRNA-seq (heterogenous cells)](https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/q/3116/96)
  - [Filtering step for read counts data](https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/q/2440/96)
- Remove `[filtering]` tag; these are about reducing sequence redundancy, which (as common as it is) probably doesn't warrant its own tag

  - [How do I find identical sequences in a FASTA file?](https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/q/2817/96)
  - [How can longest isoforms (per gene) be extracted from a FASTA file?](https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/q/595/96)
  - [How can I extract the longest N isoforms per gene from a fasta file?](https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/q/6705/96)

I'm not sure about the remaining posts. Some might be improved by dropping the `[filtering]` tag, or by replacing it with a different tag, or maybe it's the best term to use and we should simply clarify usage on the tag wiki.

- [How to safely and efficiently convert subset of bam to fastq?](https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/q/2149/96)
- [Filter BAM file for read pairs where one or both of the reads starts with a given sequence pattern](https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/q/2812/96)
- [How to filter Ensembl cDNA and ncRNA FASTA files by primary assembly?](https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/q/4076/96)
- [Select top 100 genes ranked by variance in read counts](https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/q/4128/96)
- [Why does a very strong BLAST hit get lost when I change num_alignments, num_descriptions or max_target_seqs parameter?](https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/q/2846/96)
- [Filtering out all seqs with mutations of list2 from list1](https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/q/2816/96)
- [Any fast options to query large VCF bed intervals?](https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/q/2554/96)

Comment: I agree that `filtering` isn't a very good tag, but I don't think `quality-control` covers it either. For instance, removing specific reads from a fastq file doesn't seem to come under quality control (although the specific question you cite was indeed a quality issue). Maye we need a `parsing` tag?

Comment: Well, it depends on *why* one is removing reads. If you want to reduce the size of the data, it's sampling. If you want to get rid of contaminant reads, it's quality control. If you want to more closely examine reads with particular nucleotide composition, that's...filtering? There are a lot of operations we can do on read data (or any data)--sorting/ranking, sampling, deduplicating, etc.--and not all of them need a tag.

Comment: I guess? Maybe we should just stick to the relevant format tags (`fastq`, `sam`, `vcf`, `gff` etc) and leave it at that?

Comment: What was the outcome of this discussion? I have pretty strong opinions on this topic but don't want to make a fuss if it's already been decided and dealt with.

Comment: @Geraldine_VdAuwera Please do share your opinions in an answer. I'm less sure of my initial assessment, and I certainly don't think the mods/high-rep users ever converged on a consensus.